# How to provide double click callback on ion-option?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ion-select

I have an ion-select list. Now, when I select an option, I am triggering one callback using (**ionSelect**). But I want to trigger another callback when user double clicks on an option. My code is:

```
 <ion-select interface="popover" >
            <ion-option *ngFor="let item of macroList" [value]="item.MacroName"
                        (ionSelect)="previewMacro(item)">{{item.MacroName}}
            </ion-option>
 </ion-select>
```

Is there any way to distinguish **click** and **double click** event in ion-select? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: ionic is mobile first.. They do have (press) and other gestures https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures

Comment: How to apply tap or press gesture on ion-select?

Comment: no.. only ionSelect seems to fire. you could raise a github issue if you want such a feature.. tried it in stackblitz